# How to handle answers that no longer reflect the edited question

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

I'm curious: how are we supposed to handle questions that have been changed such that older answers no longer reflect the questions being asked? 
In the context and spirit of [this meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5539/is-it-considered-good-practice-to-edit-your-question-after-answers-have-been-giv) what do we do for (or to) existing questions who've been edited such that answers:

1. are invalidated
2. are out out of context
3. are answering questions no longer present.

Here's an [example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/97969/what-would-drive-people-to-risk-death-in-the-deep/98006#98006) of the 3rd case (which I answered yesterday). The highest rated answer at the moment, Motosubatsu's answer, answers *a third question which has since been edited out*. Personally I like his answer to the 3rd question, but was confused as I had not seen it when writing my own answer (because it was edited out).

**In the example above, should the question that has been edited out be edited back in to prevent confusion to future readers?**

**In general case, what is the recommended procedure?**

Comment: The question should be rolled back I think as it is unfair to those who put time into answering.

Comment: @Bellerophon The question was edited so as to be not put on hold. I don't think the answer has been invalidated, completely, since it still answers the premise of the question in it's current state.

Comment: @sphennings Sorry, I was answering in a general case. I haven't looked at the specific question.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302373 This is the closest I could find on this topic. The answers don't fully address your question but it might help.

Answer (score 3):

The post was edited because it was at risk of being put on hold. Each post should ask a specific answerable question. The second question of the post was edited out, because in addition to being a second question, it was about creating plot not building a world. By removing the second question the post was made specific, answerable, and about building a fictional world.

It's policy to not make edits to questions that invalidate existing answers. It's also policy to edit questions so that they aren't placed on hold. I don't think we've had a discussion about what to do when these two policies come into conflict.

In this case since the answer still answers the core premise of the edited question, I don't think the answer has been invalidated.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302373) might be the closest to what you're looking for, although it only sees from the author's edit right perspective.

Answer (score 1):

General issue was already discussed network-wide meta:

[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745)

Generally  if  answer was invalidated, then there are two options:

1. Question was looking OK when answer was posted. It is OK to roll it back and comment - unless rollback would invalidate other answers. Either way, it is **not right** to downvote such answer.
2. Question was looking close-y when answer was posted. Especially if there was close votes and person who answered had [view close votes privilege](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). In that case the answerer is at fault, and should vote / flag to close, or work with OP to clear up the question, instead of answering. In such case, treat bad answer as bad answer: delete if it's yours. Request edit and/or downvote if it is not.

   Bottom line - **we should edit too broad and opinion based questions, or or put them on hold faster**, to prevent such answers from even being posted before question is in good shape.

Comment: I disagree with 2. Although the person has *close vote privilege*, for him, the question might be answerable, and thus it's not his fault for answering the question. If he VTC **and** answer, then it's his fault.

Comment: Overall, this is a good answer. But personally, I would not edit a too-broad or opinion based question without OP's consent, just to make it a good question.